# C programming strchr returns pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   const char str[] = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
   const char ch = '.';
   char *ret;

   ret = strchr(str, ch);

   printf("String after |%c| is - |%s|\n", ch, ret);

   return(0);
}
```

This code is copied from tutorialspoint.

From what I understand, `ret` is a pointer to a character. To use the value/ what the pointer is pointed to, I do `*ret`.

However, in this example, just by calling `ret`,`printf()` prints out `.tutorialspoint.com`. Why don't we use `*ret` to get `.tutorialspoint.com` since the string is the value in `ret`, which is accessed by `*ret`?

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour if the character is not in the string.

Comment: To avoid it, he must use `strchrnul`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `%s` conversion specifier properties. When used in `printf()`, it expects an argument of type `char *` and so it gets. All is well.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1

> `s`
>  If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.<sup>280)</sup> Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. [...]

In other words, to print out a *string* using `%s`, you have to supply the pointer to the start of the string, that is `res`, not `*res`.

Answer (score 1):

> To use the value/ what the pointer is pointed to, I do `*ret`.

Yes this is useful if code needs to use that value, a single character only.  But code wants to print the contents of a *string*.  A *string* is a sequence (or array) of characters up to and including the null character.

> Why don't we use `*ret` to get `".tutorialspoint.com"` since the string is the value in `ret`, which is accessed by `*ret`?

`*ret` resolves to a single a character.  `printf("%s", ...` expects a pointer to a sequence or array of characters.  By using `printf("|%s|\n", ret);`, `printf()` knows the address of the beginning of the *string* and can then print the initial character `'.'` and then subsequent ones `'t'`, `'u'`, `'t'`, ... until encountering a null character.

---

Better code would have checked the `ret != NULL` before attempting the `printf()`

```
ret = strchr(str, ch);
if (ret != NULL) {
  printf("String after |%c| is - |%s|\n", ch, ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "since the string is the value in ret, which is accessed by *ret"

No. A string in C is a number of chars ending with `\0`. So `*ret` will point to the first char of the *many*. There is no unitary value of a String as e.g. in Java.

`*` is the dereference operator.`*ret` will give the `.` since you use `*` to access the pointed element. The `%s`-printf format uses a pointer to chars (the pointer is denoted only by the name `ret`). It goes on until it encounters `\0`, the terminating character.

The function `strchr` from Linux man(3):

> The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of
>          the character c in the string s.

You could implement it manually with a while loop and simply incrementing the pointer. However, you would still need the `%s`-specifier to print it. Or the tedious for loop and a function call on every char. *Inefficient.*

*Note*: Every for-loop is to be represented by a while loop, so the above mentioned loops are not firmly set.

Comment: "Every for-loop is to be represented by a while loop" What do you mean? `for` is _similar_ to a `while` loop with stuff added before/within, but there are some cases where it's tricky to emulate the same behaviour using `while`, and really, why bother trying?

Comment: just theoretically possible